# Regex: Unable to do negative lookahed

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Here's my input text:

> Intel Core i3-4170 3.7GHz

I'm trying to replace `3.7GHz` with `XXX`

Here's my pattern:

`/\s(?=[^\s]+(.*?GHz)$)/`

but this matches: `i3-4170 3.7GHz`

if I add the *global* flag I get what I need in the 2nd group, but I'm not sure if that's reliable.

https://regex101.com/r/ARa1tG/1

Comment: Can you provide another Example of Input Text, Because I don't know why you would use such a complex Regex for a simple pattern match like this.

\d+\.\d+GHz   This regex would also have done the Job for this Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\b[^\s]*GHz\b
```

see the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ARa1tG/2)

Comment: Simpler: `[^ ]*GHz`

Comment: Even simpler: `\S*GHz` - the second `\b` might be useful but the first doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another way can be - more specific - :

```
/[\d.]*\dGHz/g
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/ARa1tG/4)

Comment: You're capturing `.ghz` and  `3ghzodiac`. https://regex101.com/r/plKEJy/1

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

`\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?ghz\b`

```
\b    // word boundary
\d+   // 1 or more digits
(?:   // optional group (not captured)
\.\d+ // a dot, then 1 or more digits
)?    // end of group
ghz   // literal
\b    // word boundary
```

- Flags: g, i
- Steps: 91

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CI529i/2)